# SQL Server Snapshot Replication and SRDF compatability

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, snapshot

Is there anything that breaks down if you use snapshot replication and then use Symmetrix Remote Data Facility (SRDF) from EMC Corporation for disaster recovery (DR) on the snapshot publisher.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2's snapshot replication feature.  We have 3 machines:

1. the original server
2. validation server
3. DR server

I am wondering if the SQL Server snapshot agent would break anywhere when using SRDF.

Specifically I am asking is: On the DR system, would the DR snapshot agent understand all the tags added by the original snapshot agent? Is there any information on how to reconfigure the agent?

Answer (score 1):

I'd check with EMC's tech support, however I seriously doubt anything at the SAN level will have an effect on SQL Server snapshots themselves.

Snapshots at the software layer are simply files that are handled just like any other file at the SAN hardware level.

Our Dell SAN has some software that integrates with SQL Server to allow you to create snapshots from SQL Server Management Studio, but again, that is a snapshot of the entire file system - not a specific database file.